# How can I get a collection of all monolog loggers in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I have a factory class that creates different objects and I have a lot of loggers defined for each type of object.
And I want to get all loggers collection in my factory. Before I just used a ContainerInterface in my factory constructor, but since Symfony 5.1 container autowiring is deprecated.
Now I can not find a way to get a collection of loggers. I tried to use

```
!tagged_iterator { tag: 'monolog.logger' }
```

and also tried to set a tag for LoggerInterface and get a tagged_iterator for it, but it didn't work. I suggest that it is because loggers are not real classes.

Comment: It's actually easy enough to add a ContainerInterface alias to your services.yaml and continue with your existing code.  But I understand the desire to refactor.  If you know the actual service ids in advance then I would think that a service locator would do the trick?

Comment: @Cerad , I have read an [article about locators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html) , but do not yet understand how it can help me. Please, could you explain your advice?

Comment: In your current code did you have several $container->get('logger1') lines of code.

Comment: in my code we have an agreement that loggers in configuration have the same name, as factory objects, so I just use

```$container->get('monolog.logger.' . strtolower($name));```

Comment: Have you tried [defining a service locator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#defining-a-service-locator) and injecting it?  Or do you not know all possible values of $name?

Comment: The MonologBundle will create channel based logger aliases in the [LoggerChannelPass](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/LoggerChannelPass.php) and not have them as part of the regular config. As such they might not be available yet. You can collect them in a custom CompilerPass that runs after the one from Monolog. As far as I know you don't have to prioritize it manually, but see [the docs for how to do it](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#controlling-the-pass-ordering)

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill but as you say the logger services are a bit unusual.  Seems like they should be tagged or be taggable by LoggerInterface but I ran some test and could not get it to work.  Here is a brute force approach which relies on logger services having ids of monolog.logger.name:

```
# Start with a service locator class
namespace App\Service;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator;

class LoggerLocator extends ServiceLocator 
{
    // Just to specify the return type to keep IDEs happy
    public function get($id) : LoggerInterface
    {
        return parent::get($id);
    }
}
...

# now make the kernel into a compiler pass
# src/Kernel.php
class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
...
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loggerServices = [];
        foreach($container->getServiceIds() as $id) {
            if (!strncmp($id,'monolog.logger.',15)) {
                //echo 'Logger ' . $id . "\n";
                $loggerServices[$id] = new Reference($id);
            }
        }
        $loggerLocator = $container->getDefinition(LoggerLocator::class);
        $loggerLocator->setArguments([$loggerServices]);
    }

# and now we can inject the locator where it is needed
class SomeController {
    public function index(Request $request, LoggerLocator $loggerLocator)
    {
        dump($loggerLocator);
        $logger = $loggerLocator->get('monolog.logger.' . $name);
```

Seems like there should be a way to do this just through configuring but a pass is easy enough I guess.